# slider function doesn't add up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i created two sliders with an value between 100 and 1000. the thing where im struggling now is how to add them together in another input in html. i tried a couple of things bud none of them worked properly. here is what i got so far:

html code:

```
    <div class="box1">
    <input type="range"  min="100" max="1000" value="0" step="100" onmousemove="showValue1(this.value)"/>
    <p id="tbox1">
    <input type="text" id="value1">
</div>

<div class="box2">
    <input type="range" min="100" max="1000" value="0" step="100" onmousemove="showValue2(this.value)"/ onchange="updateInput(.value)">
    <p id="tbox2">
    <input type="text" id="value2">
</div>

<div class="box3">
    <input type="text" id="value3" value="0">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
      var value11 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
var value22 =document.getElementById("value2").value;
var answerG = (+value11 + +value22)


function showValue1(newValue)
{
document.getElementById("value1").value=newValue;
}
function showValue2(newValue)
{
document.getElementById("value2").value=newValue;
}

$('#value3').val(answerG);
function updateInput(answerG){
    document.getElementById("value3").value = answerG;
}
```

the thing im trying to do is add the two slider values together and let it work like it should. it is not working now because i have to refresh the page to get the right value. i want when i slide the slider that the value changes the way it should.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are using jquery ui.  This would be easier for people to answer if there was a fiddle that works to where you have it.  Then people can fiddle with it.  You'll probably get a bunch of answers then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some jQuery there, but a lot more javascript. If you're going to load jQuery, you might as well use it. Anyway, here is a working script and a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n98852jp/):

HTML:

```
<div class="box1">
    <input  id="1" type="range"  min="100" max="1000" value="0" step="100" value="100" />
    <p id="tbox1"></p>
    <input type="text" id="value1">
</div>

<div class="box2">
    <input id="2" type="range" min="100" max="1000" value="0" step="100" value="100" />
    <p id="tbox2"></p>
    <input type="text" id="value2">
</div>

<div class="box3">
    <input type="text" id="value3" value="0">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[type=range]").change(function(){
        $(this).siblings("input").val($(this).val());
        $("#value3").val(+$("#1").val() + +$("#2").val());
    });
});
```